# Try: Except: always returns the Except

Tags: python

I'm facing the following problem in Python 2.x:

Basically, I'm getting a variable's current and previous value with each iteration. On the first iteration prev_var won't be defined just yet so I tried using the Try Except function, but for some reason the Except... option is always returned with each iteration so prev_var is always equal to var. Is there a fix / more elegant way of doing this?

Sorry for the non code block, I'm doing this on my phone.

```
def main():
    var = 0

    try:
        prev_var = prev_var
    except NameError:
        prev_var = var

    #then at the end of main:
    prev_var = var
    var += 1
```

Sorry for my noobishness.  Thanks for your time. I'm using Cinema 4d, if it matters.

Comment: Have a read of http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php

Comment: Of course it does, you haven't assigned `prev_var`

Comment: Not getting your point, Where is the iteration thing ?

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as correct to help those reading this in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You name `prev_var` in the `local namespace` of the function, you need to make it `global`:

```
prev_var = 0
var = 0

def main():
    global prev_var
    global var 

    prev_var = var
    var += 1
```

When you assign the variable in the function, it is picked up by the `garbage collector` when the function ends. To stop this happening you have to either return the variable into something to be picked up later. Or you declare the variable in the `global namespace` before the function.

Note that if you declare it in the `global namespace`, you don't need to use the keyword `global` in the function, Python will search for it in all enclosing namespaces (this includes `global`). However it is good practice and makes the code clearer.

Looking at the code, you probably want to do the same with var. I've shortened the code to what you should really need.

In terms of best practice you should avoid using `global` variables as it can cause mass headaches as your code grows, better to pass variables in to the `function` as `arguments` and return them into variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your assigning value outside for loop, try this

if **name** == "**main**":

```
var = 0

for x in range(0, 5):

    try:
        prev_var = prev_var

    except NameError:
        prev_var = var

    finally:
        prev_var = var
        print ('prev_var '+str(prev_var))
        var += 1
```